# SQL How to return the record with the most recent date and also highest int value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, top-n

I have to return the most recent row in a SQL database, grouped by `CallID`. The 'most recent' in this instance means the most recent DepartureDate and the highest Departuretime (int) on that date. See below example for your reference:

```
set dateformat dmy
create table #Temp
(
Callid nvarchar(6), 
Linenum nVarchar(6), 
Engineerid nvarchar (4), 
Departuredate DateTime, 
Departuretime int
)
insert into #Temp 
Values (
'100000','1','AToo','05/09/2017','57896'),
('100000','1.5','DBok','05/09/2017','57898'),
('100000','1.75','DBok','05/09/2017','57895'),
('100000','2','GKar','04/09/2017','59805'),
('100000','3','ALee','05/09/2017','54895'),
('100001','1','GKar','08/09/2017','54000'),
('100001','2','GKar','08/09/2017','58895'),
('100001','2.25','ALee','08/09/2017','56875'),
('100001','2.5','DBok','07/09/2017','59000')

select * from #Temp
drop table #Temp
```

What I want to return for the above, is the below two records:

```
CallID  Linenum  Engineerid  Departuredate  Departuretime
100000  1.5      DBok        05/09/2017     57898
100001  2        GKar        08/09/2017     58895
```

Comment: This has been asked and answered many many times but you did a GREAT job posting the details. If you provide such good detail and consumable data in your posts you will continue to get great answers. Now if you could just teach everybody else to post nice clear questions. :D

Comment: Sorry Sean, went searching in Google and found references to the Row_Number per Mureinik, but I didnt see the key bit which was adding Desc (or Asc) after each order by column in the OVER clause. That did the trick! Will remember this for next time!

Comment: Nothing to apologize for at all. You did a great job posting your question. I look forward to the next one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `row_number` window function to order the records per `callid` and then just take the first:

```
SELECT CallID, Linenum, Engineerid, Departuredate, Departuretime
FROM   (SELECT CallID, Linenum, Engineerid, Departuredate, Departuretime,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CallID
                                  ORDER BY Departuredate DESC, Departuretime DESC) AS rn
        FROM   #Temp) t
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: Brill! Forgot about the Desc after the order by, that did the trick!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a trick with `TOP 1 WITH TIES`

```
select TOP 1 WITH TIES * 
from #Temp
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CallId ORDER BY Departuredate DESC,Departuretime DESC);
```

`ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CallId...)` will restart the row numbering for each `CallId`. So there are many rows with a `1` marking the *highest*. `TOP 1` would pick just the first row of the result set, but with `WITH TIES` it will return all *first* rows, if there are more than one.